# I cant get the java file to give me error

Tags: java

I created a main Java program that works like a bank giving a user their balance, withdrawls and transfer money.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab12 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Creating Two BankAccounts
        BankAccount B1 = new BankAccount(1000, "ASU_ACCOUNT_110");
        BankAccount B2 = new BankAccount(500, "ASU_ACCOUNT_100");
        double amount;
        Scanner scan  = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Account Deposit
        System.out.println("Please Enter amount to deposit into ASU_ACCOUNT_110 Account");
        amount = scan.nextDouble();
        if(!B1.deposit(amount))
            System.out.println("Error depositing amount in account. Please enter positive value.");
        else
            System.out.println("Successfully deposited $"+amount+". The current balance is "+B1.getBalance() );

        //Account Withdrawal
        System.out.println("Please Enter the amount you would like to withdraw from ASU_ACCOUNT_110");
        amount = scan.nextDouble();
        if(!B1.withdraw(amount))
            System.out.println("Error withdrawing amount. You are either overdrawing or you have entered a negative value");
        else
            System.out.println("Successfully withdrew $"+amount+". The current balance is "+B1.getBalance());

        //Account Transfer
        System.out.println("Please Enter the amount you would like to transfer from ASU_ACCOUNT_110 to ASU_ACCOUNT_100");
        amount = scan.nextDouble();
        if(!B1.transfer(amount, B2))
        {
            System.out.println("Error transfering amount. You are either overdrawing or you have entered a negative value");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Successfully transferred $"+amount+".\nThe current balance in ASU_ACCOUNT_110 is "+B1.getBalance());
            System.out.println("The current balance in ASU_ACCOUNT_100 is "+B2.getBalance());
        }

        //Account Display
        System.out.println("\nThe details of the two accounts are:");
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
        display(B1);
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
        display(B2);
    }

    public static void display(BankAccount B)
    {
        System.out.println("The Account Number is "+B.getAccountNumber());
        System.out.println("The balance is "+B.getBalance());
    }
}
```

I created a second class that has methods and gets and calls the balances

```
public class BankAccount {

    private String AccountNumber;
    private double balance;

    public BankAccount(double balance, String accountNumber) 
    {
        this.balance = balance;
        this.AccountNumber = accountNumber;
    }

    public boolean deposit(double amount) 
    {
        return true;
    }

    public double getBalance() 
    {
        return balance;
    }

    public boolean withdraw(double amount) 
    {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean transfer(double amount, BankAccount b2) 
    {
        return true;
    }

    public String getAccountNumber() 
    {
        return AccountNumber;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I enter a negative amount for the deposit, withdrawal, transfer, I am not getting the error that I put in the main class

Any thoughts?

Comment: You seem new to Stack Overflow.  So the people who answer get credit, click the up arrow if their question is helpful.  Click the down arrow if it is not related to the question.  Click the checkmark if their answer solved your problem.  Thanks!

Comment: You have some good answers below about how your methods in `BankAccount` need to be done. However, when you start writing real bank software for a living, PLEASE don't use floating point numbers to represent money! :)

Answer (score 2):

You do not check if the number is negative anywhere in BankAccount.deposit(double).  You need to check if the code is negative like this:

```
public boolean deposit(double amount) 
{
    if(amount<0)
    {
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your methods in BankAccount always return true. You can't expect them to sometimes signal failure unless you provide an implementation that does so.

For instance:

```
public boolean withdraw(double amount) 
{
    return true;
}
```

Will never signal failure because it **always** returns true. In order for your methods to behave the way you want them to, you must add more complex behavior. Something like:

```
public boolean withdraw(double amount) 
{  
    //if the withdrawal is positive and does not exceed the balance
    if (amount >= 0 && amount <= balance)
    {
         //remove money and signal success
         balance -= amount;
         return true;
    }
    //if either condition failed, signal failure
    return false;
}
```

It looks like you simply forgot to implement these methods. Either that or you posses a fundamental misunderstanding of programming.

Answer (score 0):

The deposit, withdraw and transfer methods always return true. Therefore you will never see the error message.